# MaterialDesignInXaml TextBox and other UI elements unreadable when disabled

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

In our MaterialDesignInXaml project, we have some configuration pages which look like this:

[Page Viewable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1yzR.png)

During processing, the configuration pages are disabled, but they should still be viewable. However, they look like this:

[Page Not Viewable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKVPb.png)

In the App.xaml, we've included these resources:

```
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Teal.xaml" />
```

Can anyone advise on getting disabled UI to appear more readable?

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult to reproduce without your XAML code, but you can probably try to play with the Opacity and Foreground of the disabled items while disabling.